# Redirect test.com/* to test.com/tmp/* using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've just moved my main domain website to a sub-directory, But the search engines still have the old urls listed in there Index. Till the time fresh URL's get listed.

Is there any way to redirect those requests to that sub-directory. (except index.php)

**Old URL**: test.com/hello

**New URL**: test.com/tmp/hello

*(But there should be an exception to this redirect this should not work for test.com/index.php)*

I tried some codes but it either redirects whole url or throw a 500 Error.

Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!index\.php|tmp/)(.+)$ /tmp/$1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But when I add this, even `test.com` gets redirected to `test.com/tmp/`

Comment: thanks buddy. It worked. Can you please explain this part `^/(?!index\.php|tmp/)(.+)$` ? so that I can make some more modifications.. As for now the images & css of my `index.php` page just got vanished

Comment: `(?!index\.php|tmp/)` is negative lookahead that fails the match if we have `/index.php` or `/tmp/` at the start of the URI. `(.+)` matches 1 or more of any character in URI and `$1` is back-reference of this captured value.